# Populate Gridview DropDownList from Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am attempting to fill the Gridview with values from the database. Initially all values will be `null`. However, I want to be able to save the data in the database. (all the above works). Now, when I to 'continue' from when i saved. i cannot get the data to fill in on the cells that contained data.

C# Methods

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        if (Session["usernameSess"] == null)
        {
            var returnUrl = Server.UrlEncode(Request.Url.PathAndQuery);
            Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx?ReturnURL=" + returnUrl);
        }
        else
        {
            if (GlobalFunctions.GetADGroup(Session["usernameSess"].ToString(), "IT") == true
                || GlobalFunctions.GetADGroup(Session["usernameSess"].ToString(), "Accounting") == true)
            { }
            else
            {
                var returnUrl = Server.UrlEncode(Request.Url.PathAndQuery);
                Response.Redirect("/AccessDenied.aspx?ReturnURL=" + returnUrl);
            }

            if (Request.QueryString["emptyValue"] != null)
            {
                lblUser.Text = Request.QueryString["CreditCardUser"].ToString();
                lblError.Visible = true;
            }
        }

        string chName = GlobalFunctions.GetDisplayName(Session["usernameSess"].ToString());


        string email = GlobalFunctions.GetUserEmail(Session["usernameSess"].ToString());
        BindUserList(ddlUsers, email);
        BindGrid(sender, email);
    }
}


private void BindGrid(object sender, string email)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conStringTOA);
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("GetCreditCardEntries");
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", email);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@chName", ddlUsers.SelectedValue);
    cmd.Connection = con;
    sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
    sda.Fill(dt);
    gvCreditCards.DataSource = dt;
    gvCreditCards.DataBind();
}
```

ASP.NET GRIDVIEW

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvCreditCards" runat="server" Visible="true" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="id" HeaderText="ID" ItemStyle-CssClass="gvCCPadding" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="fin_transaction_date" HeaderText="Transaction Date" ItemStyle-CssClass="gvCCPadding" ItemStyle-Width="50%" DataFormatString="{0:MM/dd/yyyy}" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="acc_account_name" HeaderText="Account Name" ItemStyle-CssClass="gvCCPadding minWidth" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="fin_charge" HeaderText="Charge" ItemStyle-CssClass="gvCCPadding" DataFormatString="{0:C}" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="fin_transaction_description" HeaderText="Vendor Name" ItemStyle-CssClass="gvCCPadding minWidth" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="mch_state_province" HeaderText="State" ItemStyle-CssClass="gvCCPadding" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Description" ControlStyle-Width="150px">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtUserDescription" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("toa_user_description") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Receipt (Y/N)" ControlStyle-Width="75px">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlReceipt" runat="server">
                    <asp:ListItem Text="" Selected="True" Value=""></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Yes" Selected="False" Value="Yes"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="No" Selected="False" Value="No"></asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="GL Code" ControlStyle-Width="200px">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlGLCode" runat="server" DataSourceID="ds_AccountCode" DataValueField="toa_account_name" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
                    <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Text="" Value=""></asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Department" ControlStyle-Width="200px">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDepartment" runat="server" DataSourceID="ds_Department" DataValueField="toa_businessDepartment" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
                    <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Text="" Value=""></asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Location" ControlStyle-Width="200px">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlLocation" runat="server" DataSourceID="ds_businessLocation" DataValueField="toa_site" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
                    <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Text="" Value=""></asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#e9e9e9" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#e9e9e9" ForeColor="#D71826" />
    <EmptyDataTemplate>
        Empty Gridview
    </EmptyDataTemplate>
    <EmptyDataRowStyle ForeColor="#D71826" />
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: When you continue, are you causing a postback?

Comment: when the save button is clicked there is an autopostback but i would still like to click save, then walk away from the computer and come back to it open the webpage and have it populate the gridview with the saved data from the database.

Comment: Okay, so your BindUserList method; are you using this to select the user and once the user is selected, it populates the grid?

Comment: precisely!!! :) within the gridview as you probably saw, are dropdownlists within the template fields. my first inclination is that that they are overwriting the data from the database because the 'description' column pulls all the information from the database very nicely.

Comment: Your BindUserList has a variable ddlUsers, but it's never declared in the Page_Load event

Comment: WHOOPS, i forgot to erase that before i posted. the last part of Page_Load should look like this

BindUserList(email);
BindGrid(sender, email); 

and then

private void BindUserList(string email)